# IGrouping Model not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.6

I have the following classes as my viewmodel. Due to requirements, I have to use IGrouping instead of a normal IList or IEnumerable. I have to group ExtraCostOption according to the Types.

I have attached image of my view that will explain the requirement.

My problem is that the FirstCostOption do not get populated at all but all the other values are populated.
Could anyone point me to a direction? 
      [image]

```
public class ExtraCostOption
{        
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
  public OptionCategory Category { get; set; }
  public string SourceId {get;set;}
}
public class Product
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Cost {get;set;}
  public List<IGrouping<string, ExtraCostOption>> FirstCostOption { get; set; }
}
```

My razor code is :

```
        <div class="sm card content">
        @if (Model.FirstCostOption .Any())
        {
            foreach (var optGroup in Model.FirstCostOption)
            {
                <h5>@optGroup.Key</h5>
                for (int i = 0; i < optGroup.ToList().Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="card">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => optGroup.ToList()[i].SourceId)
                        <label class="control checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => optGroup.ToList()[i].IsSelected)
                            <span class="control-indicator"></span>
                            <span>
                                @optGroup.ToList()[i].Name
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>  
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
```

My controller code looks like this:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Process([FromBody]Product viewModel)
```

Comment: Im looking at the code and  public class SourceId {get;set;} would cause an error.

Comment: @BadDub could you explain why that would be?

Comment: I've just added the code to VS and you are declaring this as a class when it looks like it was meant to be an int going by SourceId? Also you dont give it a name. Its giving me an error in VS for these exact reasons.

Comment: @yuvs, that's just incorrect C#

Comment: @BadDub i see the error. However, that is the copying issue. In my code, the sourceId is a string. Let me rectify it in the question

Comment: @Andrei it was a copying issue. In my real code, the sourceId is a string. I have just rectified it

Comment: @yuvs, i would suggest you to paste your actual code here. if there are any other differences, it will take a while for people to figure out. So if you really want help, post real code

Comment: this is unrelated but `IGrouping` inherits from `IEnumerable`. So you could do `foreach (var opt in optGroup)` instead of `optGroup.ToList()[i]` inside the   loop

Comment: @Andrei unfortunately the Product class and the view page code base is very huge to post hence the reason behind posting a smaller chunk of code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the _FirstCostOption does not get populated_ (we do not know your data), but your view will never bind to your model when your submit (look at the `name` attributes of the for controls). You need to create a view model for your grouped `ExtraCostOption` items (containing a `string Name` (Key) and a `List<ExtraCostOption> Options` property and use nested `for` loops or custom `EditorTemplates`. And then the `FirstCostOption` will be a `List<>` of that view model.